# CodeRAD2 - L10N Localization

Tags: codenameone

I'm trying to add l10n support in my app but can't find useful documentation or tutorial to do that in a codeRAD2 project. Anyone who managed to build a codeRAD2 application with the possibility to select different languages?

Answer (score 1):

Localization in Codename One is separate from CodeRAD. See the [developer guide](https://www.codenameone.com/developer-guide.html) section on localization.

Unfortunately, due to the move to CSS. The experience of localization is "sub par" since it requires that we create a separate resource file for localization and edit it manually as a resource using the designer tool.

I assumed there's an issue on improving that (since I wanted to do it for a long time) but there isn't. I just filed one [here](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/issues/3632).